# Strptime from factor variable in wrong format

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to use strptime() to parse dates from a factor variable--but there is a catch.  My dates (incorrectly) list the days and the month as SINGLE rather than DOUBLE DIGITS. For example, my date would say: 5/5/2012 14:02 instead of 05/05/2012 14:02.

Thus, NA values are returned when I run the code:

```
strptime(var,"%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
```

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capital `Y` will do it:

```
test <- "5/5/2012 14:02"
strptime(test,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2012-05-05 14:02:00"
```

Comment: @thelatemail, would you explain the difference? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @OmarGonzales - `%Y` is for `20YY` or `19YY` dates, `%y` is for just `YY` dates.